# Line spacing and font type html E-mail signature

Tags: html, html-email

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 252px;">
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;font-size:14px;">
<td style="width: 3%; height: 125px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 94%; height: 125px; text-align: center;">
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Terry Mueller</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Private Private</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Aus 20, 89054 Dettingen, Germany</p>
E-Mail: <a href="mailto:terry.mueller@capcap.com">terry.mueller@capcap.com</a></td>
<td style="width: 3%; height: 125px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 2px;">
<td style="width: 3%; height: 2px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 94%; height: 2px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 3%; height: 2px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;font-size:12px;">
<td style="width: 3%; height: 125px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 94%; height: 125px; text-align: justify;"><strong>Important Note:</strong> This e-mail and any attachment are confidential and may contain trade secrets and may well also be legally privileged or otherwise protected from disclosure. If you have received it in error, you are on notice of its status. Please notify us immediately by reply e-mail and then delete this e-mail and any attachment from your system. If you are not the intended recipient, please understand that you must not copy this e-mail or any attachment or disclose the contents to any other person. Thank you for your cooperation.</td>
<td style="width: 3%; height: 125px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my first time programming html. I would like the final result to look like this:[image]

So i basically have to set the line spacing to zero and I want the font type to be Calibri (Body). Further the E-mail link should not be underlined and i want the font color to be black not blue. Can't figure out how to do that in html. Any help is appreciated. The result should be as compatible as possible with as much as feasible. I am aware that this is a noob question : )

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first have to import the font from Google fonts. Google fonts will give you the line to paste in the head of your HTML. Then you could use in-line styling but add it to each element. style="font-family: Calibri; line-height: 5px;". There may possibly be an easier way...

Comment: Thanks that worked for me.

Comment: @BroNKo web fonts do not render the same across all email clients. There are only 3 devices that render web font. [Check this litmus article](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/). You will need a fallback font for all email clients and force outlook to render a web safe font or it will render system default which is Times New Roman.